# go back and "stop at"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> How many of you people who 20 years ago doubted now go back and **stop at** the words he said. We never appreciated what he told us and called him a crazy and mad man, but he foresaw everything we did not.

Is *stop at* correct or something else used?

Other example

> How many of you now look back and **stop at** this man's words. He was right and we were wrong. Wish we would have listened.

Comment: The first sentence appears to be a rhetorical question and a sentence jammed together. Other than that, it's comprehensible and it's not awkward.

Comment: It's poor quality English, almost certainly produced by a non-native speaker (the NP *a crazy and mad man*, for example, isn't something any native speaker would be likely to produce). It's easy enough to understand that by ***stop at*** he means something like ***pause** [and take seriously, reflect upon]*, but that's not a natural use of the verb.

Comment: Neither example is a particularly idiomatic use of "stop at".